# JSTL Number Format: How to construct this pattern?

Tags: java, jsp, formatting, jstl, decimal

I'm trying to create a number formatting pattern in JSTL:

```
<fmt:message var="myPattern" key="" />
```

What would be the pattern key for achieving this result:

```
 Input number: 123456789.00
Output format: 123.456.789,00
```

- In simple words: Decimals indicator is the comma. Grouping indicator is the dot.
- setLocale solutions will not work for me. Solution must be purely pattern based.
  (Controllability issues).
- Assume that the pattern will come straight out of a db

Comment: Tried this pattern `pattern="###.###.###,##"` ?

Comment: @SanKrish - Doesn't work. Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple decimal separators in pattern "###.###.###,##"

Comment: What do you mean by *purely pattern based*? How did you output that numbers?

Comment: @ink.robot does my answer help you out . comment below my answer if you have any issues still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using the `fn:substring` function ,

```
<c:set value="123456789.00" var="phone"/>
<c:out value="${fn:substring(phone, 0, 3)}.${fn:substring(phone,3,6)}.${fn:substring(phone,6,9)},${fn:substring(phone,10,12)}"/>
```

dont forget to add ,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

tag to it .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't know the length of the number.   So you could use the default number pattern:

```
<c:set var="output"><fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${yournumber}"/></c:set>
```

Now **output** will have the format: 123,456,789.00

Next use **fn:replace** to swap the period with the comma (using @ as a placeholder).

```
<c:set var="output" value="${fn:replace(output, ".", "@")}"/>
<c:set var="output" value="${fn:replace(output, ",", ".")}"/>
<c:set var="output" value="${fn:replace(output, "@", ",")}"/>
```

Or as one statement:

```
<c:set var="output" value="${fn:replace(fn:replace(fn:replace(output, ".", "@"), ",", "."), "@", ",")}"/>
```

Note: I didn't test these lines to make sure they have no typos, so please report back if you try them and had to fix them.